# how to hide console using cx_Freeze on OSX

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, cx-freeze

I used tkinter created simple GUI, then I used cx_Freeze created .exe file, when I open .exe file it shows console other than GUI window. What I want is to hide console, just to show GUI window.

1. python 3.6.3
2. cx_Freeze 5.1.1
3. platform: macOS Sierra 10.12

hello.py file code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, BOTTOM
root = Tk()
root.title('Button')
Label(text='Hello').pack(pady=15)
Button(text='Button').pack(side=BOTTOM)
root.mainloop()
```

setup.py file code:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
base = None
executables = [
         Executable('hello.py', base=base)
              ]
setup(name='simple_Tkinter',
  version='0.1',
  description='Sample cx_Freeze Tkinter script',
  executables=executables
  )
```

Comment: Possible workaround use a website, I by no means take any responsibilty of, http://py2exe.net/

Answer (score 2):

Add This in your setup.py file(main problem)

```
import sys

base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform == 'win32' else None
```

This too(Just for precaution)

```
buildOptions = dict(
    packages=['scrollFrame', 'searchSetup', "tkinter", "threading", "sqlite3", "openpyxl", "re"],
    include_msvcr=True,
    excludes=['numpy', 'scipy', 'matplotlib', 'pandas', 'jinja2', 'flask']
)
```

Add this in your setup() function

```
options=dict(build_exe=buildOptions)
```

Complete Code-

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# To compile for windows use---> python setup.py bdist_msi
# To compile for mac use---> python setup.py bdist_dmg

buildOptions = dict(
    packages=['scrollFrame', 'searchSetup', "tkinter", "threading", "sqlite3", "openpyxl", "re"],
    include_msvcr=True,
    excludes=['numpy', 'scipy', 'matplotlib', 'pandas', 'jinja2', 'flask']
)

import sys

base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform == 'win32' else None

executables = [
    Executable('MedSort.py', base=base)
]

setup(name='MedSort',
      version='2.0',
      description='Medical Indent management',
      options=dict(build_exe=buildOptions),
      executables=executables)
```

You can find the solution to the same [here](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#windows-command-prompt-appears-briefly)

Comment: Thanks! For me, the real change was what you've proposed:  `python setup.py bdist_msi` for Windows and for mac use:  `python setup.py bdist_dmg`. I didn't realized it was different from the `python setup.py build` in linux!